# python- draw a angry and surprise face

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I use this code and tried to change the code to get angry and surprise face. But I could't do it. Can any one help me?

```
import turtle

smiles = turtle.Turtle()
smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye one

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye two

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(0,0)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(100,90)   #right smile

smiles.penup()
smiles.setheading(180) # <-- look West
smiles.goto(0,0)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100,90)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an angry face we can create the mouth by just inverting the values for the smile part in your current code:

```
smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(0,50)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100,90)

smiles.penup()
smiles.setheading(180)
smiles.goto(0,50)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(100,90)
```

Result:

[image]

To make it look more like an classical angry face emoji such as the one shown below:

[image]

We need to add angry eyebrows and move the eyes down:

```
import turtle

smiles = turtle.Turtle()

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-105,155)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.goto(-45,115)

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-75,75)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(105,155)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.goto(45,115)

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(75,75)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(0,25)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100,80)

smiles.penup()
smiles.setheading(180)
smiles.goto(0,25)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(100,80)

turtle.done()
```

Final result:

[image]

Improving this angry face to match the emoji more and making a surprise face would follow a similar process. *Hint: make a full circle for the mouth of the surprise face.*

The key to turtle graphics is to understand that first value corresponds to the x-coordinate and the second value corresponds to the y-coordinate. Once you understand that you can draw anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is for angry face:

```
    import turtle

smiles = turtle.Turtle()
smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye one

#angry
smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-55,170)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.goto(-85, 190)


smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(75, 150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye two

#angry
smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(55, 170)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.goto(85, 190)

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(0,50)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100, 90)   #right smile

smiles.penup()
smiles.setheading(180) # <-- look West
smiles.goto(0,50)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(100, 90)

turtle.done()
```

and for surprise face:

```
import turtle

smiles = turtle.Turtle()
smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(-75,150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye one

smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(75, 150)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(10)     #eye two


smiles.penup()
smiles.goto(0,50)
smiles.pendown()
smiles.circle(-100)

turtle.done()
```